# Unable to retrieve object from dstore, after changing the value of the id property

Tags: dojo

For the following data store that only contains one item,

```
     var Model = require('dmodel/Model');
     var Memory = require('dstore/Memory');
     var jsonSchema = require('dmodel/extensions/jsonSchema');
     var declare = require('dojo/_base/declare');

     var formStore = (declare([Memory]))({
            Model: jsonSchema(formSchema),
            idProperty: "formId",

     });

     var formProperties = {
            "formName": "formName",
            "formId": 'xyz',
            "formType": 'formType'
      };

      formStore.setData([formProperties]);
```

I want to do the following

```
var item = formStore.getSync('xyz');

//get a property object from an data object,
var property = item.property('formId'); 

//request a change in the value of this property
property.put('abc');

formStore.getIdentity(formStore.data[0]) //returns 'abc'

**BUT**

formStore.getSync('abc')  //returns undefined, even though it shows as 'abc' in the data array.
```

Even though the value of the property changed, I am unable to retrieve it any more by the new Id.

Comment: Try removing the item from the store, changing it's `formId` and then putting it back in the store. I am not sure that your approach will work here.

Comment: @Himanshu I have observers watching the properties of the object in other parts of the application, if I remove it and add it back, I would have to reinitialize the observers all over the place.  That is the only reason why I was trying to do this.  I can do it if there is no other way, its just a bit annoying.

Comment: And how observers are connected to object in store? Why you'll have to reinitialize them?

Comment: //request a change in the value of this property
property.put('abc'); - probably there must be formStore here?

Comment: @KirillStepanov the code is correct, see here under Data Modelling for more details - https://github.com/SitePen/dstore

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks confusing, but seems I understood it correctly.
From my point of view you have two options here:

1. Use some another value as idProperty which won't be changed;
2. Remove initial item and place new one with new id;

Changing id of item in store is bad idea.